# Prove that if every sequence of functions converge everywhere also converges in measure, the measure is countably additive

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

The Varadhan's probability theory text mentions that countable additivity is key for a sequence of functions that converges almost everywhere to converge in measure (The proof is on p.12 [here](https://math.nyu.edu/%7Evaradhan/course/PROB.ch1.pdf)). Now I am curious how to prove the other direction: if every sequence of functions that converge almost everywhere also converges in measure, then the measure is countably additive.

The approach I am thinking of is to use reductio: first assume that every $f_n$ that converges to $f$ almost everywhere also satisfies $f_n \rightarrow f$ in measure, and then assume the probability measure $P$ on the probability space $\langle \Omega, \Sigma, P \rangle$ is not countably additive, and we try to derive a contradiction.

In fact, there is [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3134458) giving an example of a sequence of functions that converges a.e. but does not converge in measure when the measure is not countably additive. (And this does seem to fit in with my reductio approach.) Does this suffice to prove the result we want? Is there any approach that does not rely on a counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this implication is true.

I am assuming you are beginning with a set function $\mu\colon \Sigma\to [0,1]$ that is finitely additive and monotone, and that $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.  Also by assumption, pointwise a.e. convergence of a sequence of measurable functions implies convergence in measure.

Let $A_k\in\Sigma$ be a sequence of pairwise disjoint sets.  Then $\chi_{\bigcup_{k=1}^{n} A_k}\to \chi_{\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k}$ pointwise, and thus also in measure by assumption.

Therefore we have for each $\epsilon\in (0,1)$, there is $N$ so that for $n>N$,

$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=n+1}^{\infty} A_k\right)
=\mu\left(\left\{\chi_{\bigcup_{k=n+1}^{\infty} A_k}>\epsilon\right\}\right)
=\mu\left(\left\{\left|\chi_{\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k}-\chi_{\bigcup_{k=1}^{n} A_k}\right|>\epsilon\right\}\right)<\epsilon\text{.}$$

We then estimate (with the help of finite additivity)
\begin{align*}
\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k\right)-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_k) &\leq 
\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k\right)-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mu(A_k)\\ &=
\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k\right)-\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n} A_k\right)\\
&=\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=n+1}^{\infty} A_k\right)<\epsilon\text{,}
\end{align*}
and letting $\epsilon\to 0$ gives us
$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k\right)\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_k)\text{.} $$
On the other hand, by monotonicity and finite additivity we always have for each $n$,
$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k\right)\geq \mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n} A_k\right)= \sum_{k=1}^{n}\mu(A_k)\text{,} $$
whereby we have
$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k\right)\geq  \sum_{k=1}^\infty\mu(A_k)\text{.} $$

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much. A remaining question just to clarify: is indexing the sequence of measurable functions intended to define them on a sequence of (increasing, in this case) sets so that the first step is possible?

Comment: @ellenying I'm not sure I'm following your question.  The functions I'm using are characteristic functions.  In general, if $A$ is a set, $\chi_A$ denotes the characteristic function of that set, which is equal to $1$ on elements of $A$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the clarification.